# Is it possible to find out which number is bigger without using an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm doing some small program for a beginners programming course and in my program I have 2 variables which hold numbers. Anyway I need to find out which number is bigger and print the appropriate message according to it, for example I have:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
```

I need to print:

"it is true that y is bigger than x";

Now the thing is that I know I can use a simple if statement but I'm not allowed to use it, now it makes me wonder, is it even possible? If so, how can I do that? How can I check which number is bigger WITHOUT doing something like:

```
if (x > y) 
    answer = true;
```

...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you can do:

```
boolean answer = x > y;
```

The expression `x > y` is just an  expression of type `boolean`. While `boolean` expressions are *often* used for conditions in `if` statements, loops etc, they don't have to be - simple assignment works fine too.

It sounds like you want the reverse though:

```
boolean answer = y > x;
```

Then you can use the value of `answer` to build the string to display...

Comment: Ok that's what i needed! as simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

Use the ternary operator:

```
System.out.println(x > y ? "It is true that x is greater than y" : "");
```

Answer (score 3):

ternary operator "?:"

```
String output = (x > y)? "x is greater than y":"y is greater than x";
```

Answer (score 2):

The ternary conditional operator that others mentioned will work.  Assuming you are looking for creative ways to do this rather than practical ones, here's another method:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
while(y > x){
  System.out.println("It is true that y is bigger than x.");
  return;
}
System.out.println("It is false that y is bigger than x.");
```

The `while` is just acting as a fancy `if`, because the `return` means the otherwise infinite loop will only execute at most once.

Here's another example that instead relies upon short-circuit boolean evaluation:

```
public static void main(String...args){
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
  boolean answer = (y > x);
  boolean testTrue = answer && printTrue();
  boolean testFalse = testTrue || printFalse();
}

private static boolean printFalse() {
  System.out.println("It is false that y is bigger than x.");
  return true;
}

private static boolean printTrue() {
  System.out.println("It is true that y is bigger than x.");
  return true;
}
```

Of course you shouldn't do this in real production code, but it can be fun to think of unorthodox ways to code something and it can be helpful for exploring the language.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as Java but you do not specify Java in your question.  In Java there are multiple ways to get the same result that involve testing the boolean expression `x > y` somehow, such as the ternary operator.  I would consider these equivalent to an explicit `if` statement.

Other possibilities:

- Compute the square root of `x - y`.  This will raise an exception if `y` is bigger.  Catch the exception in the caller and report that `y` is the larger quantity.  If there is no exception, report that `x` is the larger.
- In LISP, Ruby or another language that supports the symbol type, form a list `((symbol x, x), (symbol y, y))` and sort the list.  Then report the second symbol as the variable with the larger value.
- If using assembly, BASIC, PL/1, etc. you can use an arithmetic expression to choose the target of a `GOTO` statement.  Depending on whether `x` or `y` is larger, execution will resume at a different part of the code.  Or use the list-sorting trick in the previous bullet to select the `GOTO` label.
- In general, the expression `((x - y) / abs(x - y) + 1) / 2` will produce 1 if x is larger and 0 if y is larger.  This result could be used to choose data, a function, etc. out of a list of two alternatives, producing conditional behavior without an `if` statement.

Comment: Because he tagged Java he did not need to specify Java in the question...isn't that what tags are for?

Comment: He did say a beginning programming course.  I hope his course does not assume that Java is The Way It Is Done TM.

Comment: Ye i know i didnt mention java in the question because i already know c# and it doesn't matter for me what code language answer i'll get. Anyway this solution is too advanced but it is defantily the most interesting one i recieved in this post :) very apperciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion (but I would not recommend it)

```
public int compare ( int a , int b )
{
    switch ( a )
    {
          case Integer.MIN_VALUE :
              switch ( b )
              {
                 case Integer.MIN_VALUE :
                    return 0 ;
                 default :
                    return -1 ;
              }
           default :
              switch ( b )
              {
                  case INteger.Min_VALUE :
                      return 1 ;
                  default :
                      return compare ( a-1 , b-1 ) ;
               }

    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution but a switch cases is too advanced for this specific question

Comment: I am teaching a class and wanted to show them a<b using a switch-case. This is by far the greatest solution I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

(a+b)/2 + Abs(a-b)/2 is the bigger number.

Answer (score 0):

I know in some languages you can use short-circuit evaluation to construct the answer.

The expression  `(A && B)` always evaluates to B if A is true.  If A is false then B is never evaluated.
Similarly `(A || B)` evaluates to B if A is false.  If A is true B is never evaluated.

Though I'm not 100% sure of Java, the expression you want is:

```
String output = ((x > y) && "it is true that X is greater than Y") 
  || (((x < y) && "it is true that X is less than Y")
  || "it is true that X is equal to Y");
```

Comment: You can leverage short-circuit evaluation (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099288/is-it-possible-to-find-out-which-number-is-bigger-without-using-an-if-statement/8099478#8099478)), but your answer won't compile because it mixes `boolean` types with `String` types.