# Java program that determines whether a given integer has one or several digits without the use of an `if` statement

Tags: java

I'm asked to make a java program that determines whether an inputted integer `n` has one or several digits, and the program must output "`n` has just one digit" or "`n` has several digits" respectively. This seems easy enough by using an `if (n>=10)` statement, but I'm not allowed to use those and I'm thus confused as to what I'm expected to do.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: you can use the conditional expression (ternary operator). Also, maybe `n` can be negative, in which case `n>=10` may be insufficient as a condition.

Comment: Math.exp() should be able to do this.

Comment: If this is from some sort of beginner java course, they probably just want you to use other ways of expressing a conditional, otherwise it's probably a puzzle to do something more for the fun of it than the practicality. Can you give any more context?

Comment: Take the absolute value, convert to a string, use String#length() as the number of digits. This only works for integers.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I'm allowed to use the ternary operator. Using string.lentgth() is allowed and a good idea, although I'm not sure how to deal with outputting the respective statements.

Comment: You can use a ternary operator and return the result. `return (Math.abs( n / 10 )  < 1 ) ? "only one digit" : "several digits";`

Comment: Who is disallowing you from writing an `if` statement? If you are under artificial constraints, please edit the question to include the full details. It is possible you have misunderstood the constraints.

Comment: @kaya3 My teacher is not allowing me.

Comment: Does this answer your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099478/7607132)?

Answer (score 0):

How about a hashmap with Boolean keys: true and false and string values you want to display?

So, something  like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Boolean, String> m = new HashMap();
    m.put(Boolean.TRUE, "n has just one digit" );
    m.put(Boolean.FALSE, "n has several digits" );

    int n = 14;

    System.out.println(m.get( Math.abs(n) < 10));
}
```

You can also get more dynamic output by using a functional interface and a lambda:

```
    HashMap<Boolean, Consumer<Integer>> mFancy = new HashMap();
    mFancy.put(Boolean.TRUE, x -> System.out.println(x + " has just one digit") );
    mFancy.put(Boolean.FALSE, x -> System.out.println(x + " has several digits") );

    mFancy.get(Math.abs(n) < 10).accept(n); // 14 has several digits
```

Obviously this is all very contrived, but it does show that you can think of a `Map` as a switch statement

Comment: That would be a rather large HashMap.

Comment: David I finally get it. You should add some more detail to your answer. Something like `print(myMap[abs(n)>=10])`. Your answer seems correct but it's hard to upvote without a little more detail.

Answer (score -1):

My answer assumes an `int` type.

```
private int getDigitLength( int n )
{
    return Integer.toString( Math.abs( n ) ).length();
}
```

Explanation:

1. First account for negative values by using `Math.abs`
2. Proceed by converting `int` to `String` via `toString`
3. Lastly get string length by using `length`

#### Edit to match description more precisely:

Change return type to `boolean` and let the return statement be a comparison. Then just use the comparison in the pretty-print.

Updated function:

```
private boolean digitHasLengthOne( int n )
{
    return Integer.toString( Math.abs( n ) ).length() == 1;
}
```

Caller:

```
System.out.println( "Number has more than one digit: " + digitHasLengthOne() );
```

#### Second edit to comply with exact strings:

Define map of answers:

```
Map<Boolean, String> answers = new HashMap<>();
answers.add( Boolean.TRUE, " has just one digit." );
answers.add( Boolean.FALSE, " has several digits." );
```

Function remains as after first edit:

```
private boolean digitHasLengthOne( int n )
{
    return Integer.toString( Math.abs( n ) ).length() == 1;
}
```

Pretty-print:

```
System.out.println( n + answers.get( digitHasLengthOne( n ) );
```

This case retrieves the answer based on provided boolean key. Avoids `if` and ternary.

Comment: well, that gets you the length but doesn't really answer the question of how do you indicate if a number has more than one digit without an `if` statement.

Comment: Fine. Just change the return type to `boolean` and return statement to `return Integer.toString( Math.abs( n ) ).length() == 1;` Can use it in a print statement.

Comment: OP says the print statement should say `n has several digits` or `n has 1 digit` without using `if` statement. So you still haven't solved that. The two other answers I've seen are ternary operator (which to me seems like cheating but who knows what the professor wants) and the Map from Bool to string. So if we combine your revised answer with the Map answer we have a full solution.

Comment: If the pretty-print needs to be matched exactly then supposedly ternary operator is what they are looking for.

Comment: That could be. I actually prefer the map solution as it involves no conditionals at all (well except behind the scenes)

Comment: One more version since we are on maps - this works here as well, if the strings are defined as values.

Answer (score -1):

*easy-peasy Japanesey*

**Option 1:**

```
public static String check(int n) {
    return Math.abs(n) < 10 ? (n + " has just one digit")
                            : (n + " has just several digits");
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
public static String check(int n) {
    Map<Boolean, String> map = Map.of(
            true, "%s has just one digit",
            false, "%s has just several digits");
    return String.format(map.get(Math.abs(n) < 10), n);
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
public static String check(int n) {
    String[] arr = { "%s has just one digit", "%s has just several digits" };
    int i = Math.min(1, Math.max(n - 9, 0));
    return String.format(arr[i], n);
}
```

Comment: This has been proposed multiple times in the comments already. OP is uncertain whether or not ternary is allowed.